# AP with tl-wn725n v2

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I tried to set up an AP with the tl-wn725n v2 wifi dongle on my raspberry pi via instructions from the forums and some sites but ended up failing. Is there a way to set one up or is it not AP conpatible?
I am running Raspbian wheezy with NOOBS.

lsusb:
`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.`

`Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.`

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1997:2433`

**`Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.`**

Comment: Do you know what chipset is being used ? Paste the `lsusb` output here and we'll see if we can help.

Comment: Well I do not know what chipset it uses, but I'll edit the description for lsusb...

Comment: You will need to grab the hostapd that is compatible with the Realtek Chipsets. Do you have a link of the instructions that you were trying to follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorial: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=54946

1) Install hostapd & dhcp server:

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd udhcpd
```

2) Edit /etc/udhcpd.conf, set its contents like this:

```
start 192.168.42.2 # This is the range of IPs that the hostspot will give to client devices.
end 192.168.42.20
interface wlan0 # The device uDHCP listens on.
remaining yes
opt dns 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4 # The DNS servers client devices will use.
opt subnet 255.255.255.0
opt router 192.168.42.1 # The Pi's IP address on wlan0 which we will set up shortly.
opt lease 864000 # 10 day DHCP lease time in seconds
```

3) Edit /etc/default/udhcpd, set the following line to be like this:

```
#DHCPD_ENABLED="no"
```

4) Set wlan0 static IP, edit /etc/network/interfaces, contents should look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp


# WiFi AP
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.42.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
post-up service udhcpd start

#allow-hotplug wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet manual
#wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#iface default inet dhcp
```

5) Replace hostapd with a modified binary:

```
wget http://www.daveconroy.com/wp3/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/hostapd.zip
unzip hostapd.zip 
mv /usr/sbin/hostapd /usr/sbin/hostapd.bak
mv hostapd /usr/sbin/hostapd
chmod 755 /usr/sbin/hostapd
```

6) Edit /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf, contents should look like (change "RPI_AP" to the desired AP name, "AP_PASSWORD" - to desired password):

```
interface=wlan0
driver=rtl871xdrv
ssid=RPI_AP
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=AP_PASSWORD
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
macaddr_acl=0
```

7) Edit /etc/default/hostapd, set the line to be:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

8) Run hostapd:

```
sudo service hostapd start
```

9) Allow hostapd to be run everytime on boot:

```
sudo update-rc.d hostapd enable
```

10) Reboot your RPi

```
sudo reboot
```

..I followed this and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Link for modified HostAPD no more working...